# Android RSS reader with notifications

Tags: android, notifications, rss, feed

I want to know what i will need in order to make an RSS parser that also notifies you the new posts. I also want to include an "add to favorite posts" feature. I guess the RSS elements must be saved in a local database. What methods do you recommend? I'm new to Android development and i use android studio. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this guide](https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/jsondevguide) to parse `rss` feeds. Then if you're not the feeds provider and want to notify the user on new posts you should create a [service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html) within your app that checks for them otherwise you can use [GCM](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en) or [Parse](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications).

Comment: I'm not the feed provider, what service should i create to check new feeds? Do you have any link to look for more informations? Thanks